# add new fieds in Json array

Tags: javascript

i would like to update a json object

let's say that my json object is (the variable is for testing purpose, in reality i receive json from api)

```
var json = [
    {
        user: "value1",
        country: "value2",
        name: "value3"
    }
]
```

now with javascript or jquery, i want to add for example the following fields

```
firstname: "value"
```

so my final json should be

```
[
    {
        user: "value1", 
        country: "value2", 
        name: "value3", 
        firstname: "value"
    }
]
```

i've tried everything found in Stack overflow

```
json["firstname"] = "value"
```

or

```
jquery.extend
```

or

```
json.push
```

but this doesnt update my json variable or put me data outsier the ()

any suggestion ?

Comment: `json[0]["firstname"] = "value"`

Answer (score 1):

Since the object is inside the array you need to use `json[0]["firstname"] = "value"`, `json[0]` will retrieve first element from array which is the object

```js
var json = [{
  user: "value1",
  country: "value2",
  name: "value3"
}]
json[0]["firstname"] = "value";

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json,null,3) + '</pre>');
```

---

If array contains multiple elements then iterate over them and add property, You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** for that

```js
var json = [{
  user: "value1",
  country: "value2",
  name: "value3"
}, {
  user: "valude1ds",
  country: "valuesds2",
  name: "valdsdsue3"
}]
json = json.map(function(v) {
  v["firstname"] = "value";
  return v;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @jeebee : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(json,function(key,value){
     json[key]["firstname"] = "value";
});
```

Above code will add firstname to all the objects in the json array